# reading black and white pixels as an array from jpeg in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, image

im trying to learn how to read a jpeg image as an array of pixels in c++ or c. so far ive learned that i have to include a outside library such as libjpg.h.

ive been told that the jpeg is formated in a RGB structure where each pixel gives 3 values. is this true? and if so how would i read values for a purely black and white image?

the purpose of this question is that i am trying to assign a pointer to the top right corner of a white squre in a black picture.
if someone could show me how to read out the vaules that are given to me for this situation so i could assign this pointer i would be greatful.

Comment: You can get the information from [libjpeg's website](http://ijg.org/). It contains documents and example code.

Comment: dude! at least get your loops organized! put some effort bro

Comment: sorry, i was just trying to say that i understood the structure of arrays, so people wouldnt have to waste their time on that. i will remove the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you run with libjpeg. You'll allocate a buffer and then call `jpeg_read_scanlines` a sufficient number of times to get all of your decompressed image data into memory. You can read scanlines (rows) individually and reformat them as needed. If the image is grayscale, the RGB values will all be equal, so you can just read one of them.

[Paul Bourke's site](http://paulbourke.net/libraries/jpeg.c) has some pretty good usage examples of libjpeg.

Comment: thank you very much. that example site does have much clearer examples. the libjpg web page is hard to navigate. i wouldn't have been asking if i wasn't so lost. the buffer make sense to with the mind towards decompression. thank you very much for your patients. i am very new at this and know that noobs can be hard to work with.

Comment: For the record, I strongly disagree with community consensus that this is too broad. The question wasn't phrased in the best possible way, but due to your mention of libjpeg, it seemed like you had at least made a start on finding a solution to your problem. Hope I helped you further down that path.